# Saving Excel file with Python (Openpyxl)

Tags: python, excel

I have a problem, I have an Excel file (.xlsx) and this file have some buttons in it to help to change the language and a button that make a raport based of the data.
The problem is...If I write something in the file and then I save it with openpyxl the file will lose those buttons and looks like a normal excel.
What can I use to save that file with the same format?
I installed an addin to see those buttons.
What can I do?

EDIT: I tried to save it .xlsm but it doesn't open if I do that

Comment: I am still suffering from the same problem. While my buttons are connected to macros I can preserve the macros using `keep_vba=True` when opening the file. The buttons themselves disappear, however.

Answer (score 1):

`.xlsx` *dose not* have macros. Save it as `.xlsm` instead.

Comment: I tried to do this but it doesn't open if I save it .xlsm

Comment: I received the file with the extension .xlsx

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I have found a workaround for it:

#### Problem

I have an `.xlsm` file that contain few sheets, one of them has some macros and buttons, I read it on python using `openpyxl` function `load_workbook` (and passing the param `keep_vba=True` to make sure the macros are preserved), I write some data into another sheet that has no macros nor buttons, and I save the file using `.save(...)` . When I open the file using excel, the macros are still there but the buttons are no longer buttons, they became images.

#### Solution

Added a macro that creates the buttons on file opening ( and macros enabling of course). This worked very well in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wb.save('testsave.xlsm');
```